# Seating arrangements of 7 boys and 5 girls in a row.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

In how many ways can these boys and girls be arranged in a row if between two particular boys A and B there are no boys but exactly 3 girls?

Comment: Hint:  your word must contain either $AGGGB$ or $BGGGA$.

Comment: Boys can be arranged in 7! ways and girls in 5!. 3 girls between two particular boys form a block which can be arranged in 6 ways among 7 boys but what about the rest of the two girls. Thats confusing me.

Comment: So, start with the word $X=AGGGB$.  Now just just need to place $X$, $5$ boys, $3$ girls.  There are $8$ places you can place $X$ (that is, there are $8$ slots in which they $A$ could fall.  Having placed $X$, you have $8$ slots left to fill...can you finish from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What follows assumes that you are only interested in the gender distribution.  That is, you don't care if Amy and Clare change places but you do care if Amy and Bob do.  If you do care about the identity of each child, you must multiply by $5!\times 5!$ to get all the possible combinations. (Note: as two of the boys are already singled out, we should only permute the remaining $5$).

Your word either contains $AGGGB$ or $BGGGA$.

Let's count the words that contain $AGGGB$ (of course the other gives the same count).

There are $8$ places to start $AGGGB$.

Having located that block, we now have $7$ slots which we must populate with $5$ boys and $2$ girls. There are $\binom 75$ ways to do that.  Thus we get $8\times \binom 75$. Doubling to include the case $BGGGA$ we get $$16\times \binom 75=\fbox {336}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be ($8.5!.5!$).because selecting those 3 girls from 5 should matter and thet themselves could sit in $3! $ ways.and then the remaining $5$ boys could sit in $5!$ Ways

Comment: @Upstart  Not following you.  Once I've got the kids seated I can permute the boys (other than $A,B$) in $5!$ ways, and I can permute the girls also in $5!$ ways. Hence $5!*5!$.  Think of a typical pattern as $B_1 G_1 A G_2 G_3 G_4BG_5B_2B_3B_4B_5$ We can freely permute the $B_i$ and the $G_i$ while preserving the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Take $AGGGB/BGGGA$ as a block, plus $5$ boys, $2$ girls, and permute the $8$ objects

$2\times \dfrac{8!}{5!2!} = 336$

The above assumes that identities *other than those of $A$ and $B$* don't matter.
If they do, multiply by $5!5!$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we care about where each child sits.

1) If we consider the block containing A and B, we have 2 ways to place A and B in their seats

$\hspace{.18 in}$and then $5\cdot4\cdot3$ ways to seat the 3 girls in between.

2) We still have to arrange the remaining 5 boys, the other 2 girls, and this block in order, and

$\hspace{.18 in}$ this can be done in $8!$ ways.

Therefore there are $(2\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3)(8!)=4,838,400$ arrangements.